# How to format string to place variable in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read unique values for columns in `list` but unable to put variable correctly in a way that it becomes a command. If i run `c_data.ABC.unique()` directly then i get list of unique values in `ABC` column. Please suggest what is going wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
c_data=pd.read_csv("/home/fileName.csv")
list=['ABC','DEF']
for f in list:
    cl="c_data.{}.unique()".format(f)
    print(cl)

Output:
c_data.ABC.unique()
c_data.DEF.unique()
```

Comment: Don't use the `.` notation with variables, use the `[]` notation: `c_data[f].unique()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definetly check on [these indexing basic in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-basics). So, about your answer you can use the most basic indexing by brackets [] and string column name, for example c_data['ABC'], so you can iterate like this:

```
c_data = pd.read_csv("/home/fileName.csv")
list = ['ABC', 'DEF']
for f in list:
    print(c_data[f].unique())
```

If you want/need to use format method, you can just replace column name with formatted string:

```
c_data = pd.read_csv("/home/fileName.csv")
list = ['ABC', 'DEF']
for f in list:
    print(c_data['{0}'.format(f)].unique()])
```

Also, you can use bracket indexing with a list of string, which will give you another DataFrame. Then you can iterate over DataFrame itself which will give you column names:

```
c_data = pd.read_csv("/home/fileName.csv")
f_data = c_data[['ABC', 'DEF']]
for f in f_data:
    print(f_data[f].unique())
```